# Fast implementation of MD5 in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, hash, md5

First of all, to be clear, I'm aware that a huge number of MD5 implementations exist in C++. The problem here is I'm wondering if there is a comparison of which implementation is faster than the others. Since I'm using this MD5 hash function on files with size larger than 10GB, speed indeed is a major concern here.

Comment: You have these super-modern, faster-than-SSD drives, don't you?

Comment: This [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717216/what-hash-algorithms-are-parallelizable-optimizing-the-hashing-of-large-files-u) might help. I was going to suggest something you can parallelize, but I suppose it depends on how your data is stored.

Comment: @avakar: If the data is replicated, it should be at least plausible to speed up the computation by running it in parallel off of the different replicas, if the system allowed it.

Comment: @avakar: Very good point! I should have checked my I/O bottleneck :)

Comment: I would have a look at the md5 cracking programs...

Comment: @avakar: Whatever happend to good old RAID?

Comment: @KerrekSB, yeah, a RAID of SSD disks could work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the point avakar is trying to make is: with modern processing power the IO speed of your hard drive is the bottleneck not the calculation of the hash. Getting a more efficient algorithm will not help you as that is not (likely) the slowest point.

If you are doing anything special (1000's of rounds for example) then it may be different, but if you are just calculating a hash of a file. You need to speed up your IO, not your math.

Comment: That's not an answer. He didn't mention anything about architecture. For all you know those files could exist in a RAMdisk.

Comment: ... or simply in disk cache. I looked up this thread because I _found_ that the MD5 implementation used in the application I'm looking at is slowing down startup due to the hashing of many small files.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it matters much (on the same hardware; but indeed GPGPU-s are different, and perhaps faster, hardware for that kind of problem). The main part of md5 is a quite complex loop of complex arithmetic operations. What does matter is the quality of compiler optimizations.

And what does also matter is how you read the file. On Linux, [mmap](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mmap) and [madvise](http://linux.die.net/man/2/madvise) and [readahead](http://linux.die.net/man/2/readahead) could be relevant. Disk speed is probably the bottleneck (use an SSD if you can).

And are you sure you want md5 specifically? There are simpler and faster hash coding algorithms (md4, etc.). Still your problem is more I/O bound than CPU bound.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure there are plenty of CUDA/OpenCL adaptations of the algorithm out there which should give you a definite speedup. You could also take the basic algorithm and think a bit -> get a CUDA/OpenCL implementation going.

Block-ciphers are perfect candidates for this type of implementation.

You could also get a C implementation of it and grab a copy of the Intel C compiler and see how good that is. The vectorization extensions in Intel CPUs are amazing for speed boosts.

Answer (score 1):

table available here:

http://www.golubev.com/gpuest.htm

looks like probably your bottleneck will be your harddrive IO